# Garry's Mod - console commands to set entity keyvalues aren't working

Tags: garrys-mod, source-engine

In Half-Life 2, there is a gun for the Airboat. I wanted to play with this in Garry's Mod, so I tried enabling the gun through keyvalues, like you would in Hammer Editor. There is an `EnableGun` boolean keyvalue, so I tried using console commands to enable the gun. I spawned an Airboat through the spawnmenu (under vehicles), pointed my crosshair at it, and typed:

```
ent_setname "airboatandgun"
ent_keyvalue "airboatandgun" "EnableGun" "1"
```

This did not enable the gun. I thought maybe you couldn't access the gun like you could in HL2, so I tried this:

```
ent_keyvalue "model" "models/balloons/balloon_star.mdl"
```

This did not set the model. I tried enabling cheats, duplicating the entity, and reloading (although this removed all the entities.) Neither the airboat gun nor the new model appeared.

Am I doing something wrong? HL2 is properly mounted to Garry's Mod. Is the Airboat in Garry's Mod different than the one in Half-Life 2, or does the command not work at all?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you download that from the steam workshop it is HL2 Vehicles with guns P.S the mounted gun is just for decoration unless you get the workshop item

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd prefer not to download any mods.

Comment: Steam workshop is directally from steam and that is the only way to do it

Comment: So there isn't a way I could use console commands to modify the entity, so it has the gun on it?

Comment: You're essentially trying to mount an object you do not have the files for to an existing object. That's not possible without creating it yourself as your model or downloading it (if someone else has already created and uploaded to) from the workshop.

Comment: @aytimothy I do have the files, HL2 is mounted (but I didn't list that earlier, so don't take it personally.) And my guess is that since the bodygroup is there, so the data for the gun should be too.